# How to find index of item in list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am techy101 and I want to know How to find the index of an item in a list in python, I have tried the `.index` function before but that didn't give me the output I wanted, I have tried the `enumerate()` function too, again it didn't give a good output, here is my code:

```py
alphabet = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
message = list(input("enter message (only words not numbers):"))
key = int(input("enter key: "))
w = 0
compile_list = []
for eggsample in range(len(message)):
    print(f"thingy: {message[w]}")
    
    print(f"index is {message.index(message[w])}")
    number = message.index(message[w]) + key
    print(number)
    _ = alphabet[number]
    print(_)
    compile_list.append(_)
    w+=1
print("your new message is: ")
print("".join(compile_list))
```

and it gives me this:

```py
thingy: h
index is 0
2
c
thingy: e
index is 1
3
d
thingy: l
index is 2
4
e
thingy: l
index is 2
4
e
thingy: o
index is 4
6
g
```

Does anyone know how to actually find the index of the item?

Comment: How does `.index()` not work for you? `alphabet.index('h')` returns `7` for me.

Comment: What is your expected output? as have a nice day says, .index works just fine.

Comment: basically what the program is doing is encrypting a message like a letter wheel, instead of it giving me 7 (From Have a nice day) it starts from the start of the alphabet.

Comment: You seem to want to look for `message[w]` in `alphabet`! Why do `message.index(message[w])`? You need to do `alphabet.index(message[w])`

Answer (score 1):

Try to improve the code in line 8 as follows

```
print(f "index is {alphabet.index(message[w])}")
```

If you want to check the index in a list of "alphabets" instead of a list of "messages", you can use alphabet.index(value).

Comment: this is printing the result, buI want edits to the CODE, not prints, they are for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative instead of using the .index function.

```
List = [‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’, ‘d’]
Idx = 0

#this will find the index of “b” in the list
For i in range(len(List)):
  If List[i-1] == “d”:
    Idx = i-1

#this prints it
Print(f”The index of \”d\” in your list is {Idx}”)
```

Answer (score 0):

Either Replace all 'w' with 'eggsample' Or Replace eggsample with w